# Scrollable menu, login button vs login/password input

Tags: menu, input-fields

Which would be more engaging for the user a clikable button in a scrollable menu  -( log in - expanding to a dropdown)  or two input- fields: login and password and additionaly a login  button?

[image]

Comment: This sounds like the kind of microoptimization which is irrelevant for every conceivable purpose. If the user wants to login, she will login no matter what the menu looks like; if she doesn't, no menu design will "engage" her to login. Don't make the menu frustratingly hard to use; else, use whatever you fancy and turn your attention to more important parts of the design.

Comment: I agree with @RumiP. - even though bare fields in top require one less click to log in, logging in is not a very repetitive task, so it should not matter. On the other hand, fields are what users look for when they want to login. By the way, don't you want to put a "remember me" checkbox and "register" button/link? If so, it would occupy even more space, so dropdown would be even more proper in this case (especially if there are a lot of elements in the menu bar).

Comment: I agree with the above, over engineering. That said a popup is more likely to be problematic on mobile devices

Answer (score 1):

I think that the second option is much better. Login float panel will takes you more freedom to add additional options like **Sign Up**, **Remember me checkbox**, **I forgot my password link**, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm more of a one, whole, page thing for action, but both options may work.

Although both options are good and have their own advantages and disadvantages, my first question is; how is the dropdown menu coming up? does it work on all screen sizes? what happens if the user can not see it? Is there any other way to log in? do you need JS?

If you use the fields, thy will always be there, so that's a plus, if you choose the dropdown, you have to be sure that it works properly, always. Yes sounds obvious, like so many other things that don't work as expected.

How is the registration process happening? If you need a button for that, where is it going to be? You can use a dropdown for each, having both options on the screen. Or the same dropdown with different buttons/actions.

Finally, is your design better with dropdown or with fields?

All those are considerations that you have to answer.

The general rule says, be direct and clear, which means have the fields and not the dropdwon. But the general rule is not always the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use both method in one system. The idea of embedding login form in menu (like your approach) makes user login in one step. This is time saving. Also this is space saving vs placing login form in header e.g.

I have signed up in many website and I don't want to using "remember me" checkbox (security concerns) so I don't agree with @RumiP because I always need to login again on that website.

Comment: Having an option does not mean that you have to use it as a user. I think that there should be remember me as an option.

Comment: You right. I mean you always need to login again on that website so that little step always annoying you (I edit my answer).